# c# call a method with paramaters as a string variable

Tags: c#, variables, methods, dynamic, call

Hi i want to call a method:

```
public string MyMethod($MyVariable)
{
}
```

Where the variable $MyVariable contains all arguments for the function i.e.:

```
$MyVariable = "argument1,argument2,argumentn"
```

Is this possible, do i Need Special Syntax?

Comment: nope...   just  put string before the Myvariable... and lose the $.

Comment: `public string MyMethod(params string[] parameters)`

Comment: Show us some code that compiles, the `$` thing makes no sense. Are you sure this is C#?

Answer (score 2):

I can't tell if you want to pass one string containing all parameters, or multiple parameters.

**Single parameter**

```
public void Main()
{
    MyMethod("argument1, argument2, ...");
}

public string MyMethod(string parameters)
{
    Console.Write(parameters);

    return "whatever your string was";
}
```

Output:

> argument1, argument2, ...

**Multiple parameters**

```
public void Main()
{
    MyMethod("argument1", "argument2", "...");
}

public string MyMethod(params string[] parameters)
{
    foreach (var parameter in parameters)
    {
        Console.Write(parameter);
    }

    return "whatever your string was";
}
```

Output:

> argument1
>   argument2
>   ...